# [Meta] How do I get this site to e-mail all questions to me?

Tags: site-logistics

I really enjoy this site and find the information very useful, and like to contribute my own limited knowledge whenever possible. However, it is hard to keep up with this site without receiving e-mails when a new question is posted, or at least (not most ideal for me) having an RSS feed of questions posted on this site. Is there any way to receive e-mails of all the new questions posted on this site?

Answer (score 5):

There's also a [twitter feed](http://twitter.com/brewadvice) of questions.  You can have tweets delivered to your mobile if you really want to rocket up the rep curve.

Answer (score 2):

There are feeds that you can subscribe to (see the bottom of the page). If you don't use a feed reader (or know what that is) do a search for rss to email. There are a few free services that can accomplish this.

Currently the software that drives this site does not support this. Besides on higher traffic sites it isn't unusual for 50+ questions an hour. Would you really want all of those going to your email?

Also, on a site note, you can subscribe to tags if you are only interested in certain topics.

Comment: Oddly enough I had trouble finding the RSS Feed on the questions page. I just didn't look hard enough. I think the Twitter solution is really nice though.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a feature people would like, I could set up a newsletter that sends RSS updates to subscribers.

Comment: I don't know that it's necessary, but promoting the Twitter and RSS more might get people more active on the site. I just wanted some method to keep me abreast of all questions.